# How do I find the face of an object?

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, mesh, face

I'm working on a build mode but the thing of it is the player is able to deform meshes. Part of my build system includes having "snap" points thus I need to be able to find the face and recenter the snap point on deformed meshes.

So, how do I find the face of an object and the center of said face? Also how would I find the center?

[image: Rectangular Prism with snap points.]

To clarify: The end goal is to keep the snap point positioned properly with the face that has been deformed/manipulated.

Comment: Which face do you want to find?

Comment: @DMGregory Basically any of them that have been changed. In code it should go something like this: If face has been changed/deformed find it, recalculate where the snap point should go (roughly in the center), and place it there.

Comment: Do you need to find center on known face or all faces on mesh? If it changed you still know it, right?

Comment: If you know the set of vertices you've changed, you could iterate over the list of faces and recalculate the centroid of any face that includes a modified vertex. Is that the sort of solution you're looking for?

Comment: @wondra Not quite sure I follow. Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is always knowing the position/center of the current face so I can place the snap point properly.

Comment: @DMGregory Maybe something like that could work. Again though the bottom line is that I'm trying to keep a snap point in the proper position (the center of the face) so that the player can reach it. This is a bit out of my depth so sorry if I'm being confusing.

Comment: Do you mean extrude a face with an anchor/snap point(sphere) in runtime?